# Bootstrap background image not display

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[I am trying to put back ground image for my bootstrap web page but that is not show Please refer this link and see my progress work](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8615/)

I am try to put back ground image but in bootstrap format it is not display in normal format it displaying what is problem please help me

```css
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html{
    /* This image will be displayed fullscreen */
    background-image:url('http://p1.pichost.me/i/72/1968716.jpg');

    /* Ensure the html element always takes up the full height of the browser window */
    min-height:100%;

    /* The Magic */
    background-size:cover;
}

body{
    /* Workaround for some mobile browsers */
    min-height:100%;
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  /* Negative indent footer by its height */
  margin: 0 auto -120px;
  /* Pad bottom by footer height */
  padding: 0 0 120px;
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
#footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin-top:50px;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}


/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */


.panel-transparent {
        background: none;
    }

   .panel-transparent .panel-body{
        background: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.2)!important;
    }

#wrap > .container {
  padding: 60px 15px 0;
}
.container .credit {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

#footer > .container {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

#footer {
  background-color:#414141;
}


code {
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Wrap all page content here -->
<div id="wrap">
  
  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
     
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li onclick="view()"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
  <!-- Begin page content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary  panel-transparent"  id="login">
      <div class="panel-heading">User Login</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="jumbotron">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" type="email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" type="password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
       
       
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <p class="text-muted">This Bootstrap Example courtesy <a href="http://www.bootply.com">Bootply.com</a></p>
  </div><!--/row-->
    
  </div><!--/container-->
</div>
```

Comment: It displaying after the footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8616/)

Add background styles to `body`. Body will come over HTML and as default color for body is white, your image won't be displayed in the body.

[Edited#1]

Better solution would be to keep background styles on `html` and add `background: none;` to body. In this way, whole screen will be covered and content will be scrollable not the image plus, the image won't repeat. As far as footer spacing is concerned, I would suggest you to clean your code. It will be fine then. You may have written some invalid HTML.

Side note: Run the JSFiddle to test if it works. Don't press Save everytime. You updated your fiddle like 8615 times.

Comment: thanks lot and another issue you can see my footer(Bottom) has space line how can I remove that space